# Android send photo using HttpPost/HttpGet

Tags: android, post

I need to send a photo from a file stored in the SDCARD to an external Api. In order to do this, i'm using the following code:

```
String responseStr = null;
    this.setMethod(request);
    this.setParameters(tags, parameters, optional);
    String requested = mUri.build().toString();
    HttpHost host = new HttpHost(API_REST_HOST, -1,
            HttpHost.DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME);
    Log.d(TAG, requested);      
    try { 
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(requested);
        File file = new File(filepath); 
        FileEntity fileentity; 
        if (filepath.substring(filepath.length()-3, filepath.length 
                ()).equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) { 

            fileentity = new FileEntity(file,"image/jpeg;"); 
            fileentity.setChunked(true); 
            post.setEntity(fileentity);
        } 
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg;");
        HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(host,post);
```

"setMethod" and "setParameters" are own methods in order to build the Uri object. The external api takes well the parameters but not the photo. It's expecting the photo in a HttpBody Field.

Any idea? Thanks

Thanks

Comment: So you're sending the JPEG in the body but the server is saying that it doesn't see the JPEG in the body?

Comment: The server takes the image using php in this way

if($im_s = file_get_contents('php://input')){

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be the semicolon in the content type:

```
fileentity = new FileEntity(file,"image/jpeg;");
                                            ^
```