# Android Large Video Uploading to server?

Tags: android, video

Android large video uploading to php server ,I read many answer in stackoverflow.

[uploading video upto 50MB to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276647/uploading-video-upto-50mb-to-the-server)

[Android: OutOfMemoryError while uploading video - how best to chunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599305/android-outofmemoryerror-while-uploading-video-how-best-to-chunk)

[How to send HTTP POST request and receive response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038409/how-to-send-http-post-request-and-recieve-response/3038747#3038747)

i tried it but can't works for me even using `setChunkedStreamingMode()`..When i upload video its give me `OutOfMemoryError`

when i record video 5 second its works nice but more than 8 or 10 second video app force close due to `OutOfMemoryError`

**MY CODE::**

```
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.login_url)
                        + "uploadvideo");
                HttpResponse response = null;
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        Uri.fromFile(myFile));
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                String type = getFileExtension(myFile.getName().toString());

                String encodeurl = Base64.encodeBytes(data);

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            6);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("returnformat",
                            "json"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",
                            strUserid));

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("video",
                            data.toString()));

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title",
                            strVideoName));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description",
                            strVideoComments));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>" + response.toString());

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And i need upload video in `Base64 Encoded String`.And I know that memory error due to more memory than Heap-size.but i failed to upload video.

**LOGCAT**

```
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=20103KB, Allocated=15700KB, Bitmap Size=0KB)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.CharArrayBuffer.<init>(CharArrayBuffer.java:43)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.ReadWriteCharArrayBuffer.<init>(ReadWriteCharArrayBuffer.java:47)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.BufferFactory.newCharBuffer(BufferFactory.java:82)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:53)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.allocateMore(CharsetDecoder.java:261)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:218)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:488)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:181)
05-31 23:16:12.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17255):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:141)
```

Comment: i have same task to do in my app, have you succeeded to upload large files ? If yes please guide

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be setting a large byte[] to the entity. It's bound to run out of memory. You could use a FileEntity here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html

Some related questions and links

[Android send photo using HttpPost/HttpGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132104/android-send-photo-using-httppost-httpget)

Try this:
[Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post)

Comment: but i need to send video to base64 encoded string ,not as a file ,then what should i do ?

Comment: You could create the file Base64 encoded, and attach the encoded file instead.

Comment: can you  give me code for that i cant understand it ,if it  will works then i  accept your answer

Comment: can you tell me how to  convert `fileentity to Base64 String?`

Comment: No, You need to first convert the file to Base64 encoded content, and then create the FileEntity from the new file.

Comment: ok but some times converting large file to bytearray and then  base64 also comes outofmemoryerror exception.?and how to put base64 in fileentity?

Comment: Nope, try chunk by chunk conversion.

Comment: ok can you tell me any code for chunks by chunks conversiong bytearray to Base64 ?

Comment: can we continue in chat my gmail id ::`pmmayur123@gmail.com`

Answer (score -5):

If the OutOfMemory error is coming from the server, the quick fix would be to update your php.ini variables:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

(or whatever you feel comfortable with)

or if you are POSTing, then you'll also want to change

```
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: Clearly, it's the OOM is on the device/emulator.